# Add a class inside a JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, jdesktoppane, internal-class

I've been searching for this problem but it doesn't work for me.

What I did is that I have directories like this

```
|-> Games (folder)
|----> GamesCombined.java and classes
|----> games (folder)
|--------> pacman (folder)
|------------> PacmanGame.java and classes
```

Inside Games.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import games.pacman.*;

public class GamesCombined extends JFrame {
    private JDesktopPane dsktp = new JDesktopPane();
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
    private JMenu gamesmenu = new JMenu("Games");
    private JMenuItem play_pacman = new JMenuItem("Pacman"); 
    public GamesCombined() {
        super("Games");
        setLayout(null);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        add(dsktp);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(gamesmenu);
        gamesmenu.add(play_pacman);
        play_pacman.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //I want to add PacmanGame.java as an InternalFrame of this DesktopPane.
            }   
        });
        int frameWidth = 800;
        int frameHeight = 850;
        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Is it possible? or any other ways to add external class in a jdesktoppane?

Comment: You mean adding [`JInternalFrame`](http://olarila.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1616) ?

Comment: adding the PacmanGame.java as an JInternalFrame.

Comment: Does `PacmanGame.java` extends `JInternalFrame` ?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial in [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 setLayout(null);  // That's your problem
```

Don't set the layout to `null`, why are you doing this? Remove this line and add the internals like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     PacmanGame obj = new PacmanGame();
     obj.setVisible(true);
     obj.setSize(....);//and so on
     dsktop.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: In reply to if PacmanGame.java extends JInternalFrame, umm No. So should I change it? from JFrame to JInternalFrame?

Comment: Yes, change it without debut.

Comment: OHHH So, that's why! >.< I still need a lot to learn. Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Yes, a lot of practice+reading will learn you, don't worry, every way starts from the first step ;)